# update google calendar Event

Tags: iphone, google-calendar-api

I am using **Google Calendar API** to Add, Update and Delete data (events).
I want to download this data in to our local database.
It works fine, but when I download the same event again, old events remains there (old one doesn't get overwritten).

How can I overwrite the old event ?

Comment: POst you code where you try the match the old data with the new data.

Comment: how to match data @rckoenes because we does not have any unique ness

Comment: Then you can't match the data can you, you will need some way the match the data.

Comment: yup! i need the way how we do this.calendar event have any id.

Comment: The document of the Google Calendar API does specify an id, just use this to keep track of you events.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4688/discussion-between-rckoenes-and-ron)

Comment: i get the solution.thanks for conversaction.

Comment: please post the code here so community can get help also.

Comment: Try this [http://code.google.com/p/iphone-gcal/wiki/GettingStarted](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-gcal/wiki/GettingStarted) it may help u